# misunderstanding about std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10

Tags: c++, floating-point

According to my understanding (about what I read on the Internet), it seems that `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10` (which for `double` is equal to `15`) represent the number of digits a `double` can handle, for instance 1.23456789012345 but not  1.234567890123456

On the other hand, double-precision floating-point format range will go until `1.8*10^+308`, which seems to represent a number which not hold only on 15 digits.

Where is the incoherence?

Comment: The 1.8*10^308 is actually something like 181234567890123000...0000

Answer (score 4):

> ... `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10` (which for `double` is equal to 15) represent the number of digits a double can handle...

More precisely it's the number of significand digits it can store [**without loss of precision**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10).

Example in Python:

```
1e15 == 1e15 + 1
False 

1e16 == 1e16 + 1
True # loss of precision
```

Answer (score 1):

[std::numeric_limits::digits10](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10): Number of digits (in decimal base) that can be represented without change.

Answer (score 1):

The one is *significant* digits. The other is the *range* of numbers representable. So, you can have:

```
1.23456789012345*10^308
```

but not

```
1.234567890123456*10^308
```

which shows both *significant* digits `15` and the *range* `10^308`, which can be represented.